# Is it possible to edit an error text in business objects? If not, is it possible to redirect?

Tags: report, reporting, business-objects

I am working on a project in business objects where I have a webpage that lists links to reports within business objects. Users will only have access to some of these reports that are listed on the webpage. When a user clicks on a link to a report they do not have access to it will give them an error that says "the document cannot be found". We want users to recieve an error when they to view a report they don't have access to, but we want it to say something along the lines of "you don't have access to view this report". Is there a way to edit the error so that we can make it say they do not have access? If not, is there a way to redirect to another custom page when the user gets an error message?

Answer (score 1):

is this a custom app build by you?
if yes then you can't change the error message thrown by bo sdk, but you can catch the specific exception & throw back the exception you want to display.